# Dynamically add new input fields based only if the emails are not duplicated

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm doing a small task which requires doing some checks for email duplication. If the emails aren't duplicated in the input, then you can add more fields.
The code works fine for the most part with just one problem.
I'm going to list the steps to reproduce it:

1. Complete the first inputs fields however you like and then click the add more button
2. On the second row of inputs complete as you like: if  you add the same email as in the first row, then the button gets disabled. If you enter another email address, the button gets enabled. Click the add more button again.
3. On the third row complete as you please, but add another email address.
4. If you want to change the email address on the second row and put the same email from the third row in here, the button gets disabled. Now if you go to the first email input and delete any character from the input, the button gets enabled, which shouldn't happen because there are 2 duplicate emails on the second and third row.

JS:

```
let clone = document.querySelector('.js-form-content').cloneNode(true);
document.querySelector('.js-form-content').remove();
let btn = document.querySelector('.add-more');
let count = 0;

function emailHandler(clonedElement) {
  const email = clonedElement.querySelector(`input[type="email"]`);
  const allEmails = document.querySelectorAll(`input[type="email"]`);
  email.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    const emails = document.querySelectorAll(`input[type="email"]`);
    let emailsValues = []
    emails.forEach((email, index) => {
      if (!email.isSameNode(event.target)) {
        emailsValues.push(email.value)
      }
    })
    console.log(emailsValues);
    if (emailsValues.includes(event.target.value) && email.value.length > 0) {
      this.flag = false;
      btn.setAttribute('disabled', ' ');
    } else {
      this.flag = true
      btn.removeAttribute('disabled', ' ');
    }
  })

}

function createElement(clonedElement) {
  clonedElement.classList.remove('d-none');
  clonedElement.querySelectorAll('[name]').forEach(input => {
  })
  clonedElement.querySelectorAll('[name]').forEach(input => {
    const name = input.getAttribute('name');
    input.setAttribute('name', `participant[${count}][${name}]`);
  })
  count ++;
  document.querySelector('.form-content-holder').appendChild(clonedElement);
}

function addNewFields () {
  // btn.setAttribute('disabled', ' ');
  const clonedElement = clone.cloneNode(true);
  createElement(clonedElement);
  emailHandler(clonedElement);

  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input-participant-data');

}

btn.addEventListener('click', () => addNewFields());
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/make96/pen/yLEOVRP

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by creating a function which checks if there are any duplications in the array.

Add this after the `emails.forEach` method:

```
let multipleDuplications = emailsValues.some((element, index) => {
    return emailsValues.indexOf(element) !== index
});
```

I also modified the if to check if the newly added function returns true or false:

```
if (emailsValues.includes(event.target.value) && email.value.length > 0 || multipleDuplications) { 
// 
}
```